# javafx preloader

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, preloader

I'm learning javafx and I'm trying to make a splash screen of an application and I can not do it.

can you give me an idea of ​​how to make a basic splash screen.

do work behind the splash and when done to change the scene and show the scene of the application I hope your help thanks.

Comment: Please, can you improve your question? Explain what you tried so far, and what problems/errors you encountered. Show the code. Have you tried looking for a tutorial in google?

Comment: JavaFX has support for splash screens/preloaders. Then you create new JavaFX project in NetBeans there is an option to create preloader project for your app. Also you may find more info in next tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABCDIHD